# How to write List<Number> with OpenCSV?

Tags: java, spring-boot, export-to-csv, opencsv

I have the following field inside a StacItem Object:

```
@JsonProperty
private List<Number> bbox = null;
```

I made a basic implementation with OpenCSV to write this Object into a CSV, and it mostly works with this code (i'm showing just the relevant part):

```
final StatefulBeanToCsv<Object> beanToCSV = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<>(writer)
                .withSeparator(';')
                .build();
        for(StacItem item : items){
            beanToCSV.write(item);
        }
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/csv");
        httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=exportItems.csv");
        logger.info("END WRITING");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new FileSystemResource(file), HttpStatus.OK);
```

Here's the twist! In the logs of my Microservice, I see the full structure of that StacItem, and it should have this bbox field:

```
bbox=[8.24275148213394, 45.5050129344147, 7.62767704092889, 45.0691351737573]
```

While my implementation returns just this:

```
"8.24637830863774"
```

So when I open my CSV I just found the column "bbox" with one value but I need the others too..Can you please tell me why it stops on the first one or how to get the others 3?

UPDATE:
I found that this does the trick! But then...it exports just this single field for every StacItem so I lose every other field in my Object.

```
@CsvBindAndSplitByName(elementType = Number.class, writeDelimiter = ",")
    @JsonProperty("bbox")
    private List<Number> bbox = null;
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are you flushing or closing your writer?

Comment: Hi k314159, I'm using a Try-With-Resources, so it does the trick automatically

Comment: But I don't see any try-with-resources in your method above. Perhaps you're closing it _after_ you read the file and pass it back in your API. Then you're not reading the full content of the file, because what you've just written hasn't been flushed yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer k3, I didn't think about it, unfortunately shifting the return after closing the try-with-resources didn't change the result.
(It's not visible in the code above because i'm just showing the relevant snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `CsvBindByName` on every field you want to map (specify the `column` attribute of the annotation is not mandatory).

You can even use `CsvBindByPosition` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Taz! It worked like a charm, I used @CsvBindByName on every other field except the tricky one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change ?

```
 beanToCSV.write(item); -> beanToCSV.writeNext(item);
```

or

```
    for(StacItem item : items){
        beanToCSV.write(item);
    }

    // to

    beanToCSV.write(items);
```

Comment: Hi paranaaan, Yes I have already tried: writeNext doesn't exist as method of "StatefulBeanToCsv" while the second solution writes just one item unfortunately...
I found that "@CsvBindAndSplitByName(elementType = Number.class, writeDelimiter = ",")" does the trick but the drawback is that it exports just the bbox field for all the items!